# How to pass f[x] explicitly in a command

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Two days ago I have been kindly helped to construct a function that implements the [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method):

```
hal[f_, init_, nn_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{g = f, halley}, halley[0] := init; 
  halley[n_] := 
   halley[n] = 
     halley[n - 
       1] - (2 f[halley[n - 1]] f'[
     halley[n - 1]])/(2 N[f'[halley[n - 1]]]^2 - 
    N[f[halley[n - 1]]] N[f''[halley[n - 1]]]); halley[nn]]
```

It works nicely but it the function must be defined outside the command and pass only through it's head --- f --- or define inside the command as a pure function.

To limit mistakes I would like to know how to pass f[x] also.

To resume

```
  f[x_]:= Cos[x]
  hal[f, 1, 3]
```

and

```
  hal[Cos[#]&, 1, 3]
```

work but not

```
hal[f[x], 1, 3]
```

Comment: Is your `f[x]` actually in the form `f[x]`, or is it an expression with `x` in it?

Comment: Sorry to be late to this party, and this is really unrelated to your question, but, what is the point of the `g = f` assignment in your definition of `hal`? This seems to have no purpose, and g is never used. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution doesn't require you to modify the original definition of `hal`:

```
hal[expr_, init_, nn_Integer?Positive] /; (! NumericQ[expr@init]) := 
 Module[{symbol, f}, {symbol} = 
   Union@Cases[expr, _Symbol?(! Context[#] === "System`" &), Infinity]; 
  f = Function[#, #2] &[symbol, expr]; hal[f, init, nn]]
```

Notice this is actually a "shell" for the original `hal`. Now `hal` accepts both expression and function as its first argument:

[image]

Comment: Whoah, I just wish I was able to understand your code without spending hours going through the Mathematica documentation. In other words, I'm impressed...

Answer (score 2):

The standard Mathematica style is to pass both the expression and the variable it depends on, e.g. `D[f[x], x]`, `Solve[f[x] == y, x]`, `Plot[f[x], {x, ...}]` and so on. So if you define

```
hal[f_, x_, init_, nn_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{halley}, 
  halley[0] := init; 
  halley[n_] := halley[n] 
              = N[(x - (2 f D[f, x])/(2 D[f, x]^2 - f D[f, x, x])) 
                  /. x -> halley[n - 1]];
  halley[nn]]
```

then you could do

```
f[x_] := Cos[x]
hal[f[x], x, 1, 3]
(* 1.5708 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: A bit too late for edit, but this solution works. (changes your definition very slightly)

```
hal[f_Function, init_, nn_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{g = f, halley}, halley[0] := init; 
  halley[n_] := 
   halley[n] = 
     halley[n - 
       1] - (2 f[halley[n - 1]] f'[
     halley[n - 1]])/(2 N[f'[halley[n - 1]]]^2 - 
    N[f[halley[n - 1]]] N[f''[halley[n - 1]]]); halley[nn]];

hal[expr_, init_, nn_Integer?Positive] :=
 hal[Function[Evaluate[Cases[expr, _Symbol, Infinity][[-1]]], expr],
  init, nn]
```

The first definition has an additional head `_Function` added to the first argument.

The second definition converts your expression to a function and re-evaluates. In fact, the function can have any variable, not just `x`, as long as it has only one variable.

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work. notice in most cases `f[x]` will evaluate to a expression that don't match `f_[x_]`.

Comment: @xzczd Adding `SetAttributes[hal, HoldFirst]` makes it work

Comment: @Coolwater Then it doesn't accept something like `Exp[-x]+Cos[x]`

Comment: @xzczd Welp, the fixed version works.

Comment: Then this doesn't accept the `f` from e.g. `f[x_]=x^2` 囧

Comment: @xzczd Accidentally put brackets in the wrong position... Try it now?

Comment: No… as far as you restrict the head of `f` to `Function`, your `hal` won't work on `f` from `f[x_]=x^2`. If it "works" on your computer, you probably forget to `Clear@hal` first, because the original definition for `hal` works on function defined with pattern matching.

Comment: @xzczd the second definition doesn't have the `Function`. Thus, if you type `x^2`, it goes through the second definition and is made into a function, and that result goes into the first definition. My function seems to work even after restarting the kernel.

Comment: I mean, if you define `f[x_]=x^2`, then, `hal[f, 0, 1]` won't work.