# Expression as parameter to function that evaluates it, best way to do it?

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, parameters, arguments

I need a function fSum that computes the angular sum for some expression, like this:

**fSum[3 Sin[2 x], 0, 2 π]**

Or from a predefined function, like this:

**f[x] = 2 Sin[3 x];**

**fSum[f, 0, 2 π]**

Or plots it like this (exact syntax will probably have to be different here):

**Plot[fSum[a Sin[x]], {a, 0, 1}]**

I have this stub for fSum:

```
fSum[expr_, from_ ?NumericQ, to_ ?NumericQ] := Module[{f},
   f = ???? (* How to do this? *)
   Return[NIntegrate[Abs[D[ArcTan[f'[x]], x]], {x, from, to}]];
   ]];
```

I have asked about something similar before and have then received some helpful answers that solved the particular problem at the time. But now I need to make the `fSum` function more general so that I also can plot `fSum` relative to some plot variables in the expression (or function) passed to it. The only thing I can get to work at `????` in the stub is a hardcoded expression, which is very far from what I need. I have searched this forum and have tried many different solutions, but can not make them work in this case. It would be great if the ***expr*** parameter can be both an expression, function, and a string containing the inputform text for the expression.

Comment: The standard design is to make the independent variable an argument, just like `Table`, `Sum`, `Integrate`, etc. The syntax you're expecting is possible, but personally I don't quite recommend it. See e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/297243/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127580/1871

Comment: Thanks, I will have close look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[fSum];

fSum[str_String, rest__] := fSum[ToExpression@str, rest]

fSum[f_, {from_, to_}] := NIntegrate[Abs[D[ArcTan[f'[x]], x]], {x, from, to}];

fSum[expr_, {var_, from_, to_}] := With[{f = Function @@ {var, expr}},
   fSum[f, {from, to}]];

fSum[expr_, from_, to_] := 
 With[{symbol = 
    First@Union@Cases[expr, _Symbol?(Context[#] =!= "System`" &), Infinity]},
  fSum[expr, {symbol, from, to}]]
```

Usage:

```
Clear[f, x]
f[x_] = 3 Sin[2 x];

fSum[f, {0, 2 Pi}]
(* 11.2452 *)

fSum[3 Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
(* 11.2452 *)

fSum[3 Sin[2 x], 0, 2 Pi]
(* 11.2452 *)

fSum["f", {0, 2 Pi}]
(* 11.2452 *)

fSum["3 Sin[2 x]", {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
(* 11.2452 *)

fSum["3 Sin[2 x]", 0, 2 Pi]
(* 11.2452 *)

Plot[fSum[a Sin[x], 0, 2 Pi], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, works perfectly and very elegant! Thank you very much xzczd. I will study the last overload carefully, and hopefully I will learn a little about this strange Wolfram language.  I have been programming in many different programming languages for more than 40 years now, but never has the learning curve been this steep.

Comment: @Mikl If you have difficulty in understanding the code, feel free to continue to ask in the comment :) .

Comment: Yeah, can you please explain what is happening in the With[{symbol = ....] in the last overload. Looks very similar to sanskrit to me.

Comment: @Mikl In last overload, we're detecting the independent variable automatically. _Usually_ the independent variable in expression is a `Symbol` that's not in `"System\`"` `Context`, so we use the pattern `_Symbol?(Context[#] =!= "System\`" &)` to extract the symbol. `?`, `_`, `&`, etc. are just some shorthand, you can check their `FullForm` with e.g. `Cases[expr, _Symbol?(Context[#] =!= "System\`" &), Infinity] // Hold // FullForm` and  check their document by pressing **F1**. (Actually this isn't necessary, because almost all of the shorthand can be directly found in document by pressing F1. )

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will read up on it.

Comment: @Mikl Perhaps this is a bit easier to follow: `testfunc = Function[var, Context[var] =!= "System\`"];
fSum[expr_, from_, to_] := 
 With[{symbol = First@Union@Cases[expr, PatternTest[_Symbol, testfunc], Infinity]}, 
  fSum[expr, {symbol, from, to}]]`

Comment: Thanks xzczd, yes that is a little clearer with the test pattern separated out.  Another thing: How would you modify your solution to not compute angular sum, but instead ArcLength with the corresponding range of input parameters?

Comment: @Mikl `fArc[f_, {from_, to_}] := ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, N@from, to}]` (Then replace `fSum` with `fArc` in the other 3 definitions, of course. )

Comment: Thanks again xzczd, you are of great help so I can get on with my actual project (which is not about tricking MMA into doing what I naively expect it to).  Follow up question: Why N@from but not N@to, and what does it do in this particular case?

Comment: @Mikl It's for forcing numeric calculation. (I see you're using `NIntegrate` in `fSum` so guess you're looking for numeric result. ) Compare e.g. `ArcLength[{Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0., 2 Pi}]` and `ArcLength[{Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]`. Alternatively, you can set a `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` option to force numeric calculation.